# How to animate drawing in Swift, but also change a UIImageView's scale?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, core-animation

I'd like to animate a drawing sequence.  My code draws a spiral into a UIImageView.image.  The sequence changes the image contents, but also changes the **scale** of the surrounding UIImageView.  The code is parameterized for the number of revolutions of the spiral:

```
func drawSpiral(rotations:Double) {
let scale = scaleFactor(rotations)   // do some math to figure the best scale

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImageView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.scaleBy(x: scale, y: scale)      // some animation prohibits changes!
// ...  drawing happens here
myUIImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

For example, I'd like to animate from `drawSpiral(2.0)` to `drawSpiral(2.75)` in 20 increments, over a duration of 1.0 seconds.

Can I setup `UIView.annimate(withDuration...)` to call my method with successive intermediate values? How? Is there a better animation approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I setup UIView.annimate(withDuration...) to call my method with successive intermediate values

Animation *is* merely a succession of timed intermediate values being thrown at something. It is perfectly reasonable to ask that they be thrown at your code so that you can do whatever you like with them. Here's how.

You'll need a special layer:

```
class MyLayer : CALayer {
    @objc var spirality : CGFloat = 0
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == #keyPath(spirality) {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey:key)
    }
    override func draw(in con: CGContext) {
        print(self.spirality) // in real life, this is our signal to draw!
    }
}
```

The layer must actually be in the interface, though it can be impossible for the user to see:

```
let lay = MyLayer()
lay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(lay)
```

Subsequently, we can initialize the `spirality` of the layer:

```
lay.spirality = 2.0
lay.setNeedsDisplay() // prints: 2.0
```

Now when we want to "animate" the `spirality`, this is what we do:

```
let ba = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:#keyPath(MyLayer.spirality))
ba.fromValue = lay.spirality
ba.toValue = 2.75
ba.duration = 1
lay.add(ba, forKey:nil)
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
lay.spirality = 2.75
```

The console shows the arrival of a succession of intermediate values over the course of 1 second!

```
2.03143266495317
2.04482554644346
2.05783333256841
2.0708108600229
2.08361491002142
2.0966724678874
2.10976020619273
2.12260236591101
2.13551922515035
2.14842618256807
2.16123360767961
2.17421661689878
2.18713565543294
2.200748950243
2.21360073238611
2.2268518730998
2.23987507075071
2.25273013859987
2.26560932397842
2.27846492826939
2.29135236144066
2.30436328798532
2.31764804571867
2.33049770444632
2.34330793470144
2.35606706887484
2.36881992220879
2.38163591921329
2.39440815150738
2.40716737508774
2.42003352940083
2.43287514150143
2.44590276479721
2.45875595510006
2.47169743478298
2.48451870679855
2.49806520342827
2.51120449602604
2.52407149970531
2.53691896796227
2.54965999722481
2.56257836520672
2.57552136480808
2.58910304307938
2.60209316015244
2.6151298135519
2.62802086770535
2.64094598591328
2.6540260463953
2.6669240295887
2.6798157542944
2.69264766573906
2.70616912841797
2.71896715462208
2.73285858333111
2.74564798176289
2.75
2.75
2.75
```

Those are exactly the numbers that would be thrown at an animatable property, such as when you change a view's frame origin `x` from `2` to `2.75` in a 1-second duration animation. But now the numbers are coming to you as numbers, and so you can now do *anything you like* with that series of numbers. If you want to call your method with each new value as it arrives, go right ahead.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you!  I'll check it out today and hope to accept it as the answer.  Well done!

Comment: You might want to skip the image view and use this layer to draw itself, i.e. draw the spiral directly into `con` (the CGContext), and not make an intermediate UIImage at all

Comment: full downloadable example project here https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch04p151customAnimatableProperty/ch17p498customAnimatableProperty

Comment: I'm making progress, but still struggling.  I eliminated the UIImageView and now I use a typical UIView with overridden draw(_ rect: CGRect) for drawing.  I'm getting control in the animation layer at the right time, and I can print the correct values of "spirality".  But the graphics context appears to be for the ANIMATION layer (which is basically vacuous).  How can I draw (or trigger drawing) in the spiral's drawing layer?

Comment: Ah, yes, in that case you would want the animation layer _not_ to be vacuous. Instead of my tiny vacuous merely number-receiving animation layer, make the animation layer the hosted layer of an actual view and draw in the context when `draw(in:)` is called.

Comment: My animations trigger if (only if) they are added to a subLayer, not when added to the UIView's main layer.  After some finagling, I got both layers operating properly, but both remain visible.  I surmise that I shouldn't leave the animation layer around when not animating.   When (relative to ViewController sequencing) is the right time to add and to delete an animation subLayer?  Thanks!

Comment: I don’t agree with any of the premises in that comment so I have no response.

Comment: Fascinating.  I was reporting observations, not assumptions.  That my results are unexpected is itself a useful datapoint.  I'll go back to check some basics, and if I'm still stuck, I'll extract my code and post it.  I do appreciate the reality check.

Comment: I'm still unable to successfully animate a drawing sequence using parameters other than those for which UIView animation applies.  Yours has been very helpful feedback, but the objective of my initial question is still eluding me.  Your example didn't work for me with actual drawing.  I'm hopeful your comments and example will lead me to success, and I'll be more than happy to award a checkmark once I can get my animation working.  At present, I'm making progress and yours is the lead answer.  We both want it to work.

Comment: But I gave you a link to a downloadable project where we declare a completely new property and we _do_ animate it and it _does_ work with "actual drawing".

Comment: Eureka.  My app required a mixture of animated and non-animated drawing - so I had to redirect the static drawing into my animation layer - which took me a while to realize.  @Matt, thanks for your patience as well as your help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, in more complicated animations I would use [lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) the animation itself is built with Adobe After Effect and exported as a JSON file which you will manage using the [lottie library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) this approach will save you time and effort when you port your app to another platform like Android as they also have an [Android Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) which means the complicated process of creating the animation is only done once.

[Lottie Files](https://www.lottiefiles.com/) has some examples animations as well for you to look.

Comment: Thanks.  The point of this portion of the app is drawing figures based on multiple user input parameters; it's fundamentally a mismatch with an approach where "the complicated process of creating the animation is only done once".  Maybe Lottie would be useful in some other situation.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt provided the answer and gets the checkmark. I'll recap some points for emphasis:

- UIView animation is great for commonly animated properties, but if
  you need to vary a property not on UIView's animatable list, you can't use it. You must
  create a new CALayer and add a `CABasicAnimation(keyPath:)` to it.
- I tried but was unable to get my CABasicAnimations to fire by adding them to the default UIView.layer.  I needed to create a custom CALayer
  sublayer to the UIView.layer - something like
  `myView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)`
- Leave the custom sublayer installed and re-add the CABasicAnimation to that sublayer when (and only when) you want to animate drawing.
- In the custom CALayer object, be sure to `override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool` with your key property (as @Matt's example shows), and also `override func draw(in cxt: CGContext)` to do your drawing. Be sure to decorate your key property with `@objc`. **And reference the key property within the drawing code.**
- A "gotcha" to avoid: in the UIView object, be sure to null out the usual draw method (`override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { }`) to avoid conflict between animated and non-animated drawing on the separate layers. For coordinating animated and non-animated content in the same UIView, it's good (necessary?) to do *all* your drawing from your custom layer.
- When doing that, use `myLayer.setNeedsDisplay()` to update the non-animated content within the custom layer; use `myLayer.add(myBasicAnimation, forKey:nil)` to trigger animated drawing within the custom layer.

As I said above, @Matt answered - but these items seemed worth emphasizing.