# Is ist possible to drive a non visual property from an animatied control?

Tags: swift, core-animation

Let's say I build a control slider and I animate it through a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` so that it has momentum when I release from a drag with velocity.

Is it possible to drive a non-visual property from the animation of that slider? I was looking for some kind of callback for each frame or something that would allow me to use the animation and control a parameter from it.

Alternatively is it possible to create an animatable object myself and drive it through the same animation?

As an example think about a slider that controls the brightness of a light-bulb, which is controlled through a network protocol. Once I release the slider and it starts to animate I would need to somehow determine the slider position, calculate a related brightness level and turn that into a brightness command for the bulb.

I have looked around, but have not found a strategy to do this. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for your support!!
-mj

Comment: Can’t quite figure out what you’re asking; maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49932836/341994

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you could animate a change like that inside of an animation block but you could definitely do it using a UIGestureRecognizer. That class has delegate methods that can inform you pretty frequently about the position of a drag gesture and you could use those callbacks to calculate the "percentage" that the gesture has moved across the slider you are trying to build and use that value to set the brightness of the bulb.

To simulate the momentum you want, you will have to use the `velocity(in: )` function from UIPanGestureRecognizer and then use that value to simulate how you want the velocity to decay.

Depending on how accurate you want your slider's deceleration to be, you could either use some physics equations like `TimeToStop = InitialVelocity/DecelerationRate` where the deceleration rate is a constant that you would keep as a constant and play around with until you have a value that you like. With these values figured out, you have a lot of options for how to generate the callbacks you are looking for. I would suggest picking a constant for how many seconds between callbacks you want so that you can tailor them to the purpose (ie you don't want to make 10 network calls per second). Then, use that constant to figure out how many times you want to fire the callback and then use either an asynchronous delay or a timer to fire the callback with the slider value which will be `SlideOffset = OffsetWhenGestureEnded + VelocityWhenGestureEnded*TimeToStop + 0.5*DecelerationRate*TimeToStop^2`

Comment: Well - the UIGestureRecognizer is out of the game as soon as I let go of the slider. I want the slider to have momentum and continue to 'slide' when I release it with a velocity. The changes to the control will then be animated based on a timing curve.

Comment: My mistake, I missed the part about momentum. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry I was out for a while... I don't see how the animation drives the value in your answer above. That is what I am trying to do. Reason is that animation should reflect the actual value even if I change the animation later and it may be interrupted (by tapping the slider again) in which case the current value should match the position of the slider...