# Trouble positioning a sublayer correctly during animation

Tags: ios, calayer, caanimation

**The question is** how should I define and set my shape layer's position and how should it be updated so that the layer appears where I'm expecting it to during the animation? Namely, the shape should be stuck on the end of the stick.

I have a CALayer instance called `containerLayer`, and it has a sublayer which is a CAShapeLayer instance called `shape`. `containerLayer` is supposed to place `shape` at a specific position `unitLoc` like this:

```
class ContainerLayer: CALayer, CALayerDelegate { 

    // ...
    override func layoutSublayers() {
        super.layoutSublayers()
        if !self.didSetup {
            self.setup()
            self.didSetup = true
        }
        updateFigure()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func updateFigure() {
        figureCenter = self.bounds.center
        figureDiameter = min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
        figureRadius = figureDiameter/2

        shapeDiameter = round(figureDiameter / 5)
        shapeRadius = shapeDiameter/2

        locRadius = figureRadius - shapeRadius
        angle = -halfPi
        unitLoc = CGPoint(x: self.figureCenter.x + cos(angle) * locRadius, y: self.figureCenter.y + sin(angle) * locRadius)

        shape.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: shapeDiameter, height: shapeDiameter)
        shape.position = unitLoc
        shape.updatePath()
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'm having trouble finding the right way to specify what this position should be before, and during a resize animation which changes `containerLayer.bounds`. I do understand that the problem I'm having is that I'm not setting the position in such a way that the animation will display it the way that I'm expecting it would.

I have tried using a `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")` to animate the position, and it improved the result over what I had tried previously, but it's still off.

```
@objc func resize(sender: Any) {

    // MARK:- animate containerLayer bounds & shape position
    // capture bounds value before changing
    let oldBounds = self.containerLayer.bounds
    // capture shape position value before changing
    let oldPos = self.containerLayer.shape.position

    // update the constraints to change the bounds
    isLarge.toggle()
    updateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    let newBounds = self.containerLayer.bounds
    let newPos = self.containerLayer.unitLoc

    // set up the bounds animation and add it to containerLayer
    let baContainerBounds = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    baContainerBounds.fromValue = oldBounds
    baContainerBounds.toValue = newBounds
    containerLayer.add(baContainerBounds, forKey: "bounds")

    // set up the position animation and add it to shape layer
    let baShapePosition = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    baShapePosition.fromValue = oldPos
    baShapePosition.toValue = newPos
    containerLayer.shape.add(baShapePosition, forKey: "position")
    
    containerLayer.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I also tried using the presentation layer like this to set the position, and it also seems to get it close, but it's still off.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(animationDidUpdate))
        displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        //...
    }

    @objc func animationDidUpdate(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
        let newCenter = self.containerLayer.presentation()!.bounds.center
        let new = CGPoint(x: newCenter.x + cos(containerLayer.angle) * containerLayer.locRadius, y: newCenter.y + sin(containerLayer.angle) * containerLayer.locRadius)
        containerLayer.shape.position = new
    }
    //...
}

class ContainerLayer: CALayer, CALayerDelegate {
    // ...
    func updateFigure() {
        //...
        //shape.position = unitLoc
        //...
    }
    // ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like when the resize begins you are hard-setting the circle to the center of the size that we _will_ be at the end of the resize. — Yes, you are looking at `self.bounds` of a layer. But when the animation starts, the layer's bounds change immediately to the bounds that they will be at the end of the animation. What's drawn on the screen, meanwhile, is not the layer but its _presentation_ layer. So you are failing to coordinate with that.

Comment: Yes, you'll notice that you are getting _both_ the initial size _and_ the initial position wrong. That's because you are getting all that information from the bounds that the container layer will have at the _end_ of the animation, rather than animating from the dimensions that it has at the start to the dimensions that will have at the end.

Comment: Why doesn't `action(forKey key: #keyPath(position))` prevent the position of the ShapeLayer from being animated? It seems like it should be that simple, and it's really confusing to me that it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how what I said relates to the notion of whether the position is animated. I'm talking about the meaning of phrases in your code like `self.bounds` which you use to position and size the circle shape. I'm telling you what those phrases mean. This is about what the position _is_, not whether you animate on the way to getting there.

Comment: From that standpoint it seems to me that your title, like your focus, is a red herring. This has nothing to do with disabling animation. It has to do with what `self` is and how animation itself works.

Comment: What I mean is if I'm setting the position of the circle at the exact same spot as the end of the line, `unitLoc` it doesn't make sense to me that the circle moves off to one side or the other before coming back to the center. In the resize animation, all it needs to do is move a bit to/from the center of the container, no need for it to move laterally at all. So it seems like suppressing the implicit position animation would stop that from happening. Or, I'm misunderstanding and it's not an implicit animation and I'm using the wrong words. Either way, I don't see how to make this work.

Comment: "unitLoc it doesn't make sense to me that the circle moves off to one side" And I explained to you why it was. Watch my mouth, I'm going to say it again. `unitLoc` is calculated based on `self.bounds`. When the animation starts, `self.bounds` are the bounds that the layer will have at the _end_ of the animation. So you are jumping your circle to a position that will be correct at that time. Now the animation takes place, the circle doesn't resize or move relative to the container, and so it ends up at the right place, because that's where you put it initially, the right place for the end.

Comment: hi @Paul i can't follow all this but pls. look at my answer as it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some slight exaggeration, I was able to make it clearer what's happening in your code. In my example, the circle layer is supposed to remain 1/3 the height of the background view:

[image]

At the time the animation starts, the background view has already been set to its ultimate size at the *end* of the animation. You don't see that, because animation relies on portraying the layer's presentation layer, which is unchanged; but the view itself has changed. Therefore, when you position the shape of the shape layer, and you do it in terms of the view, you are sizing and positioning it at the place it *will* need to be when the animation *ends*. Thus it *jumps* to its final size and position, which makes sense only when we reach the end of the animation.

Okay, but now consider this:

[image]

Isn't that nicer? How is it done? Well, using the principles I have already [described elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49932836/341994), I've got a layer with a custom animatable property. The result is that on every frame of the animation, I get an event (the `draw(in:)` method for that layer). I respond to this by recalculating the path of the shape layer. Thus I am giving the shape layer a new path on *every frame of the animation*, and so it behaves smoothly. It stays in the right place, it resizes in smooth proportion to the size of the background view, and its stroke thickness remains constant throughout.

Comment: I can see those intermediate values I've been looking for now thanks to your other examples. Is there a way to capture those values that you see by "print" from within `draw(in:)` and use them outside of draw? I want to use the values to do things which are totally inappropriate to do from within `draw(in:)`

Comment: For example, in my containerLayer, using a print in `draw(in:)`, I'm watching its bounds values change during an animation. How can I use those values as the basis for setting the position of a sublayer of containerLayer simultaneously?

Comment: Is it okay to just assign a value to `shape.position` in draw?

Comment: You can do anything you want. As I say in my book: "Consider layer animation abstractly as a way of getting the runtime to calculate and send us a series of _timed interpolated values_. Those values arrive through the runtime repeatedly calling our `draw(in:)` implementation, but no law says that we have to _draw_ in that implementation: we are free to use those values however we like. In fact, we don't even have to use the values! We can implement `draw(in:)` purely as a way to _get an event on every frame_ of an animation, responding to that event in any way we like."

Comment: So is that shape a sublayer just filling it's bounds with an ellipse, having its bounds and position modified by a key value you obtain from `draw(in:)` in the container layer? Because that's what I'm going for. Which key are you using to tell the circle where to be?

Comment: I told you, I don’t even look at the incoming value. The whole key thing is just a trick to get an event on every frame. On every frame I fit the shape layer’s frame to the bounds of the green view’s layer’s presentation layer, and give the shape layer a new path, in the right place and the right size relative to that.

Comment: You're right, I missed that point. Now when you say "On every frame I fit the shape layer’s frame to the bounds of the green view’s layer’s presentation layer", how do you do that? I tried self.frame = self.presentation()!.bounds, I'm sure you know how that turned out.

Comment: Try `(self.presentation() ?? self).bounds`. :) Or maybe `self.presentation().bounds ?? self.bounds`.

Comment: that gives me the same crash...`'CALayerReadOnly', reason: 'attempting to modify read-only layer`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were talking about reading the bounds. It might help you to look directly at the code I used: currently here (future readers beware, this link will break): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/xcode12/bk2ch04p151shapeAnimation/ShapeAnimation/ViewController.swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218239/discussion-between-paul-and-matt).

Comment: In your second example here, why is the circle jiggling around as it moves and resizes? Is that the best it can be with this approach?

Comment: In the example code, the first option, ViewController is my solution. It has no "jiggling". (Maybe there is "jiggling" in the animated gif that I posted, but that's because it's an animated gif.) The others, ViewController2 and ViewController3, are failures that I'm showing you for educational purposes.

Comment: No, it didn't confuse me at all. I meant in the second animation in the answer above, the circle does generally stay in the right place but it's not totally smooth. In reworking this, to ContainerView I added ContainerLayer as a sublayer and said `containerLayer.delegate = self`. I constrain ShapeView to ContainerView, and  ShapeView draws the circle in `draw()` (with no ShapeLayer). And in ContainerLayer's `draw(in ctx:)` I have `let parent = self.delegate as! ContainerView; parent.shapeX.constant = -(self.presentation() ?? self).bounds.width/2;`

Comment: This positions the circle well during any animation, and I coordinated the duration and timing with ContainerView's `layoutSublayers(of layer:)` with `CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(anim!.duration); CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(anim!.timingFunction);` The result is similar to your second animation sample, but it's also jiggly in exactly the same way, so I'm wondering if that's just the best one can expect. Barely perceptible, but not solid either.

Comment: When I run your code, the first option, the circle is jiggling in the simulator and on a device, just like the gif.

Comment: if in your example, you make your animations autoreverse and repeat, draw a horizontal line across the y center of the green rect, change lineWidth to 1, and make the shapelayer's path a horizontal line instead of a circle, I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I answered the question that was asked, not some other question.

Comment: I put the question back to the way it was when you answered it. I shouldn't have changed it. I'll just ask a new question later.

Comment: Sorry I'm just worn out from this. If you hadn't been willing to talk it through with me I would still be at the beginning. I've not been gracious about my trouble but I am glad to have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### One aspect of this: Are you aware of implicit animation on layers?

It's a little difficult to follow everything that is being said here.

But in iOS layers try to "automatically" animate themselves. It's "easy enough" to turn off the implicit animation, something like:

```
class RepairedCALayer: CALayer {
    override open class func defaultAction(forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        if event == #keyPath(bounds) { return NSNull() }
        if event == #keyPath(position) { return NSNull() }
        if event == #keyPath(isHidden) { return NSNull() }
        return super.defaultAction(forKey: event)
    }
}
```

Again there's just literally too much for me to have time to read in the question (sorry!) but I often suffer EXACTLY what you show, since, the built in automatic animation conflicts with what you're trying to animate.

IF that is the case, you're done - "simply" block the implicit animation one way or another.

"Turning off" implicit animations requires a lifetime of study but I've included a simple approach here. I hope it helps, even if this is not precisely your issue.